# AutoTask Rest API Queue Query

Tags: node.js, api, rest

I am building a very simple app in NodeJS it queries my AutoTask Portal for New Tickets and then displays them.

I have it querying based on status, all good. My problem, is it only gives me Queue ID, I need to then take that Queue ID and query for the Queue name.

Is there an entity I can query to get that? I tried

```
https://webservices[n].autotask.net/atservicesrest/v1.0/queue
```

&

```
https://webservices[n].autotask.net/atservicesrest/v1.0/queues
```

Neither works.

Short of building a database/list of queue names & ID's is there a way I can translate the queue id to name?

I am using the RestAPI, I can't find anything in the documentation to help me.

Answer (score 2):

You would first want to query the Ticket entity information:

`https://webservices[n].autotask.net/atservicesrest/v1.0//Tickets/entityInformation/fields`

This will give you all the fields and potential picklist values, including the queueID.

Below is an excerpt and not the full response:

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "queueID",
      "dataType": "integer",
      "length": 0,
      "isRequired": false,
      "isReadOnly": false,
      "isQueryable": true,
      "isReference": false,
      "referenceEntityType": "",
      "isPickList": true,
      "picklistValues": [
        {
          "value": "5",
          "label": "Queue 1",
          "isDefaultValue": false,
          "sortOrder": 0,
          "parentValue": "",
          "isActive": true,
          "isSystem": true
        },
        {
          "value": "6",
          "label": "Queue 2",
          "isDefaultValue": false,
          "sortOrder": 1,
          "parentValue": "",
          "isActive": true,
          "isSystem": true
        },
        {
          "value": "8",
          "label": "Queue 3",
          "isDefaultValue": false,
          "sortOrder": 2,
          "parentValue": "",
          "isActive": true,
          "isSystem": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```